# set text to textview in dynamically in android-marquee

Tags: android, textview, android-scroll

How to set TextView Text as dynamically for scrolling marquee.
Please Help me Thanks Advance.

The Listview used for getting the list item to be played in the audio player is as follows.

```
    public class Audiovediolist extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
        private ListView audioList;
        private Intent frmHome;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList;
        private HashMap<String, String> map;
        private HashMap<String, String> data;
        private int Screen_Id;
        String name;
        String mSign[] ={"1","2","3","4","5"}; 
        Integer mImages[] = { R.drawable.m, R.drawable.v,
                R.drawable.mm, R.drawable.k, R.drawable.s};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_RIGHT_ICON);
            setContentView(R.layout.list);
            frmHome = getIntent();
            getIntentValues();
            initUI();
            setUI();
            uiListener();
        }
        private void initUI() {
                audioList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.audiolist_listView);
                dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        }
        private void uiListener() {
                audioList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }
        private void getIntentValues() {
            String id = frmHome.getStringExtra("Activity_Id");
            Screen_Id = Integer.parseInt(id);
            if (Screen_Id == 1) {
                getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_RIGHT_ICON,
                        R.drawable.audioo);
                this.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.audio));
                this.setTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Beige));
            } else {
                this.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.video));
                this.setTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Beige));
                getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_RIGHT_ICON,
                        R.drawable.videoo);
                 }
          }
        private void setAdapter() {
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList,
                                     R.layout.list_row, new String[] { "Image", "text" },
                                     new int[] {
                                     R.id.audiolist_row_img, R.id.audiolist_row_tv });
                         audioList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        private void setUI() {
                for (int a = 0; a <= 11; a++) {
                     map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     map.put("Image", "" + mImages[a]);
                     map.put("text", mSign[a]);
                     dataList.add(map);
                     map = null;
                }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            setAdapter();
        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            System.gc();
        }
    /*private class NextTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
                ProgressDialog progressDailog = new ProgressDialog(Audiovediolist.this);
              @Override
              protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDailog.setTitle("Please Wait");
                progressDailog.setMessage("URL Data Loading ...");
                progressDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progressDailog.setCancelable(true);
                progressDailog.show();
                }
              @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            @Override
              protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return null;
                }
             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                progressDailog.dismiss();
                }
    }*/
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
                    data = dataList.get(position);
                try {
                      NetWorkCheck netWork = new NetWorkCheck();
                      if (netWork.isNetWorkConnection(this)) {
                          if (Screen_Id == 1) {
                            //  new NextTask().execute();
                              Intent audioInt=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AudioView.class);
                                audioInt.setType(data.get("text"));
                                startActivity(audioInt);
                           } else if (Screen_Id == 2) {
                                 Intent vedioInt = new Intent(this, VideoPlayActivity.class);
                                 vedioInt.setType(data.get("text"));
                                 startActivity(vedioInt);
                                 }
                       } else {
                              netWork.alert();
                              }  
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Problem while ListItemClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
    }
    }
```

The code for audio player used is

```
public class AudioView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private ImageView mPlay;
    private ImageView mPause;
    private ImageView mBack;
    private ImageView mFar;
    private ProgressBar myProgressBar;
    // private PlayerService mService;
    private boolean boolFlag = false;
    private boolean isPausedInCall = false;
    private String url;
    private TelephonyManager mTelephoneMgr;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;
    private TextView tv;
    // private boolean serviceRunning;
    Notification notifyDetails;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.audio_main);
        getIntentValues();
        initUI();
        uiListener();
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.mulug_icon, url,
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        mTelephoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mTelephoneMgr != null) {
            mTelephoneMgr.listen(phoneStateListener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }

    private void getIntentValues() {
        url = getIntent().getType();


    }

    private void uiListener() {
        mPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        mPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        mPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        mPause.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        mBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        mFar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initUI() {
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
        mPlay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play);
        mPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        mFar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fwd);
        myProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
        myProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.green_progress));
        myProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            tv.setText(url);
            tv.setFocusable(true);
    }

    private Thread myThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < mMediaPlayer
                    .getDuration()) {
                try {
                    myProgressBar
                            .setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        // myThread.stop();
        // mMediaPlayer.release();
        mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.gc();
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        try {
            if (boolFlag == false) {
                System.out.println(FinalConstants.URL + "mobile-audio/" + url
                        + ".mp3");
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
                        this,
                        Uri.parse(FinalConstants.URL + "mobile-audio/" + url
                                + ".mp3"));
            }
            myProgressBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading Problems",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("ERRORS", "ServerFailed to Load...");
            super.onBackPressed();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                System.out.println("ringing state");
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    pauseMedia();
                    isPausedInCall = true;
                }
                notificationShow();
            }
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                System.out.println("callState Idle");
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (isPausedInCall) {
                        isPausedInCall = false;
                        playMedia();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };

    private void pauseMedia() {
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
        changePlayerIcons(false);
    }

    private void playMedia() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        changePlayerIcons(true);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.play:
            if (!boolFlag) {
                try {
                    notificationShow();
                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                    // mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "preparing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                boolFlag = true;
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                myThread.start();
            } else {
                notificationShow();
                mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
            changePlayerIcons(true);
            myProgressBar.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    changePlayerIcons(false);
                    myProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                    onStart();
                }
            });
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                }
            });
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "MediaPlayer Errors", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("ERRORS", "MediaPlayer Errors...");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.pause:
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            mPlay.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            mPause.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.back:
            int dur = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            int pos = (dur > 10000 ? dur - 5000 : 0);
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
            break;
        case R.id.fwd:
            int curpos = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            int dur2 = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
            int pos2 = (curpos + 5000 > dur2 ? dur2 : curpos + 5000);
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos2);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void notificationShow() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Mulugu Running";
        CharSequence contentText = url + " Weekly Predictions";
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(AudioView.this, AudioView.class);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AudioView.this, 0,
                notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                intent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
    }

    private void changePlayerIcons(boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            mPlay.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            mPause.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mPlay.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            mPause.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

The XML used is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/main_audio"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="     for more details check on  "
                    android:textColor="#FF0000"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" >

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/pause"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/audio_pause" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/play"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/audio_play" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pause"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pause"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@drawable/audio_play"
                    android:src="@drawable/audio_bwd" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fwd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pause"
                    android:src="@drawable/audio_fwd" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your question sholud be I have tried this and not working help me?
Please try something yourself first and if you get trouble then post your question here.

Comment: am tried but getting force close.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an example:**

```
public class TextViewMarquee extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv);  
        tv.setSelected(true);  // Set focus to the textview
    }
}
```

**The xml file with the textview:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="#ff4500"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: settext at runtine not in xml

Comment: use tv.setTExt("Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text")